# how can i make a function send automatically my tokens to the address of sender when the another erc20 token received

Tags: tokens

I am building a Smart Contract that can receive tokens and in exchange for the tokens received another token will be issued.

my problem is how can i make a function send automatically my tokens to the address of sender when the another erc20 token received

if you have code write it

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible using an ERC20 token, it would require another function call to your smart contract to say that the tokens have been sent.

There are ERCs which try to deal with the situation you have mentioned such as [ERC223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223) which would add a `tokenFallback` function to contracts for handling token transfers. If you were dealing with ERC223 tokens then you use the `tokenFallback` function to send tokens in response to tokens being received.

To implement this with ERC20 tokens you would need the person exchanging tokens to give your contract a token allowance, and then call the `claimTokens` function.

(Very) Rough sample contract:

```
contract ExchangeTokens {

    address tokenToSend;

    function claimTokens(address tokenSent) {
        uint256 numTokens = ERC20(tokenSent).allowance(msg.sender, this);
        if (numTokens > 0) {
            ERC20(tokenSent).transferFrom(msg.sender, this, numTokens);
            ERC20(tokenToSend).transfer(msg.sender, numTokens);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First you state it isn't possible with ERC20 and then you give an implementation of it with ERC20, hmm? :)

Comment: @LauriPeltonen His question asked "how can i make a function send automatically my tokens to the address of sender when the another erc20 token received" which is not possible, it is possible if you ask the user to manually call a function in your smart contract. The ERC223 contract I mentioned would also make his question possible.

Comment: i want to create a token relay like [this](https://blog.enjincoin.io/enjin-coin-bancor-token-relay-explainer-11313c0bab2) with the ERC20 because if i use the ERC223 my token relay will be not supported with the ERC20 wallet

Comment: Have a read through the Solidity contracts in your link then https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts/blob/master/solidity/contracts/BancorConverter.sol

Comment: Your question asked for something different, which is what my answer is answering

Comment: if i just copy and paste the code in [this](https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts/blob/master/solidity/contracts/BancorConverter.sol) link , it will be work ? 
matt can you contact me on facebook this is my [profile](https://www.facebook.com/moezGHL) ?

Comment: @Matt in your example, what would happen, if the first transaction was succesful, but the second fails to succeed?